# Anomaly with DetailedMerged FreeBusyViewType data returned from Exchange 2007

Tags: timezone, exchangewebservices, outlook-2007

I'm using EWS SOAP service to fetch detailed free busy data from Exchange 2007. I'm trying to fetch data between 9am and 10:30am. The data returned is in intervals of 30 minutes so 3 slots are returned.

The first part of the response from Exchange contains the MergedFreeBusy string which shows 002, which equates FREE FREE BUSY. This would indicate that between 9am and 10am the room is busy and that between 10am and 10:30am the room is busy

However the detailed view returns two entries the first with a start time of 9am and end time at 10am and the busy type is incorrectly showing as busy. This contradicts the earlier mergedfreebusy data.

When i open Outlook and check the rooms actual availability i see that the room is free between 9-10am and busy between 10am and 10:30am. So the mergedfreebusy data content is correct while the detailed data is not. Why would this be happening?

Finally to set some more context,  my timezone is GMT ( at the moment due to daylight savings its GMT+1, not sure if this should be an issue however because the response contains conflicting data).

One way i can work around this issue is to determine the bias from expected timezone that the user is requesting from. Other suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this is actually something which is covered in the MS EWS documentation. Enclosing URL in case anyone else runs into similiar problem - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655859%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx